# Como adicionar um QPushButton para o QTableWidget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt-5, widget

Estou criando uma aplicação em PyQt5 com uma tabela, utilizando as classes `QTableWidget` e `QTableWidgetItem`. A tabela possui três colunas — as duas primeiras são apenas textos e a última é um botão, que será usado para remover o item da tabela. Meu código abaixo:

```
def set_items(self, data):
    self.table.setRowCount(len(data))
    self.table.setColumnCount(3)

    current_row = 0

    for title, info in data.items():
        button = QPushButton("Remove")
        button.clicked.connect(self.__remove_item)

        self.table.setItem(current_row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(title))
        self.table.setItem(current_row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(info))
        self.table.setItem(current_row, 2, QTableWidgetItem(button))
        current_row += 1
```

O problema é que eu não consigo adicionar o botão à tabela porque o seguinte erro é lançado:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QTableWidgetItem(type: int = QTableWidgetItem.ItemType.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPushButton'
  QTableWidgetItem(str, type: int = QTableWidgetItem.ItemType.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPushButton'
  QTableWidgetItem(QIcon, str, type: int = QTableWidgetItem.ItemType.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPushButton'
  QTableWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPushButton'
```

Pela mensagem de erro, dá para ver que o problema está no `QTableWidgetItem` não aceitar um `QPushButton` ou qualquer outro *widget* que não seja `str`, `int`, `QIcon` ou uma instância da mesma classe. Minha dúvida é: o que eu devo fazer então para adicionar um `QPushButton` ou mesmo um outro *widget* para a tabela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para adicionar um widget em um `QTableWidget`, usamos o método `setCellWidget` do mesmo. Tente mudar essa linha

```
self.table.setItem(current_row, 2, QTableWidgetItem(button))
```

para

```
self.table.setCellWidget(current_row, 2, button)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Carlos!